# iOS Browser Programming Technology

Tags: ios, cocoa, safari, webkit

Except Safari, Most of the iOS browsers like dolphin, chrome, mercury,opera etc. do not use standard cocoa objects and have a very different UI than standard elements . Does anybody know what technology these browsers use? Any help would be appreciable

Comment: Are you talking about elements in the web page, or about the browser chrome?

Comment: I am talking about the browser(s) i.e. the UI does not seem to be built using standard available UI elements such as buttons or bars etc..Which technology are they using to build such apps?

Comment: Is this question browser-specific then? There are all kinds of apps that do not use standard UI components.

Answer (score 2):

If u mean UI customization, firstly check the nature UI element of native this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html)
  - this is so cool for ios developer you should look for customization [cocoa control](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/)